# asp.net mvc controller does not recognize DateTime url parameter?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am encoding an Iframe url with some date parameters:

```
var object = {
                profileID: self.profileID(),
                organisationID: self.organisationID(),
                startDate: self.startDate(), // 09/04/2013 
                endDate: self.endDate() // 17/04/2013 
            };
iFrame.src = "ExportReportAllMediaDetailsCsv/?" + $.param(object);
```

the encoded url:

```
http://dev.neptune.local/Report/ExportReportAllMediaDetailsCsv/?profileID=41&organisationID=2252&startDate=09%2F04%2F2013&endDate=17%2F04%2F2013
```

however the method that is being called sometimes does not recognize the datetimes being passed in:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'endDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime'
```

this is the method signature:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Definitions.RoleAnalystManager, Definitions.RoleProjectManager)]
public ActionResult ExportReportAllMediaDetailsCsv(int profileID, int organisationID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue I Converted the dates to UTC date time strings:

```
var object = {
                profileID: self.profileID(),
                organisationID: self.organisationID(),
                startDate: getUtcDateString(self.startDate()),
                endDate:getUtcDateString(self.endDate())
            };

function getUtcDateString(gbDate) {
    var dayMonthYear = gbDate.split("/"),
        newDate = new Date(dayMonthYear[2], dayMonthYear[1]-1, dayMonthYear[0]);
    return newDate.toUTCString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using UK-formatted date strings. Since only `endDate` isn't working, my guess is that `startDate` is being recognised as the 4th of September. On the other hand, because there is no 17th month of the year, `endDate` can't be bound to a `DateTime` object.

It sounds like you need to set your culture correctly. Try adding the following to your Web.Config, under `<system.web>`:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-GB" />
```

For more info on globalization, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It look like `endDate` sometimes is null (or simply it's not set), so you have to declare parameter as nullable type (`DateTime?`):

```
public ActionResult ExportReportAllMediaDetailsCsv
    (int profileID, int organisationID, DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate)
```

On the other hand it may be because datetime format is not recognized, so basically it can't be parsed as a valid `DateTime` value.

Comment: but it throws the exception even if its passed in and is not null, and it cant post the request unless both dates have been set

Comment: It may be because of wrong datetime format, have you tried to send your datetime string in different format?

Comment: Well datetime formats generally depends on culture. Check [standard  DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Also check @AntP answer, this may be more suitable to set application wide culture instead of formatting your datetime strings. It depends on what you need.